# C++ std::vector with always valid iterator/pointer/index/key

Tags: c++, collections, vectors

**Motivation**: Have `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` accessibility at `std::vector<T>` speed.

`std::vector` have one inconvenience - you can't store pointers nor indexes to elements if the vector grows/alters.

To overcome this problem we usually use vector of pointers / deque (if only grow) / list / etc. Having our elements in heap have significant overhead on creation, traverse, and per element access.

To store "pointer" (or key) to element in vector I have back array of indices.

Condensed version:

```
struct Key{
   int index;  // index of key_indices
};

struct Element {
    int key_index;   // never changes
    Value value;
};
std::vector<Element> data;       // usual continious vector, no magic here
std::vector<int> key_indices;    // point to data[]. these values changes when erase/insert to data
std::vector<int> free_indices;

void emplace_back(){
   // if have no free_indices
   data.emplace_back();
   key_indices.emplace_back(data.size() - 1);
   data.back().key_index = key_indices.size() - 1;
}

Key get_key(std::vector<Element>::iterator iter){
    return {iter->key_index};
}

Value& operator[](Key key){
   return data[key_indices[key.index]].value;
}

Value& operator[](int index){
   return data[index].value;
}

void erase(std::vector<Element>::iterator iter){
    free_indices.push_back(iter->key_index);
    update_indices(iter + 1, data.end(), -1);
    data.erase(iter);
}
// same with insert, emplace_front, etc.

template<class iter>
void update_indices(iter from, iter to, int shift) {
    for (auto it = from; it != to; ++it)
    {
        key_indices[it->key_index] += shift;
    }
}
```

And used like:

```
KeyContainer<Data> list;

list.emplace_back().back().x = 100;
list.emplace_back().back().x = 200;

auto key = list.get_key(list.end()-1);

list.erase(list.begin());               // all indices invalidated
std::cout << list[key].x << std::endl;  // key still valid
```

In other words Key - is array index that always points to the same element, just like pointer to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` element.

It is approximately 6-10 times faster than `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`/`list` on creation, 3-4 times faster than deque(at least with VS2015/clang). Same speed as vector when traverse/index access. And approx 10% slower with key access. I tried to use pointers instead of indices, but didn't see a difference.

Is there some ready library solution for container like this (vector with indices back-array (or ptr back-array))?

[Full code as is (just a concept proof)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/044f33b3f219f3f9)

Comment: You can store there index. Even if the vector grows the index of an element does not become invalid.

Comment: Is this asking for a review or an alternative library?

Comment: @LokiAstari But it become invalid when you insert / erase in the middle.

Comment: @tower120: Perhaps it would make sense to add a little more explanation of the required behavior. As I read it, you're saying an item is assigned a key when it's inserted, and that key remains with that item as long as the item remains in the collection. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks you are trying to create a multi index container. I would look at the boost implementation for some ideas. PS. USes classes.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes it is correct. Behavior same as pointer to std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>.

Comment: @LokiAstari Maybe :), could you show how to use it to achive this behavior?

Comment: @LokiAstari According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4208349/1559666 multi index container use some sort of set as internal memory storage, which means it can't be possibly as fast as vector. The key thing not to index / order / reorder array (if I understand boost's rationale correctly ), but to keep indexes in actul state when erase / insert occurs see 'update_indices'. Or I understood you wrong.

Comment: @tower120 No problem. But a bit more research your side first. The first big step in C++ is encapsulation. Do the same thing in a class with methods so that nobody else can mutate the state. Then I'll do a big review with lots of suggestions.

Comment: @LokiAstari - I actually hoped that there is some production ready library, maybe like multi_index_container... It seems
naturally to me to have some "handler" to element in array and not to pay overhead for this. But if there is no known implementation... I'll finish this collection class and post full code here tomorrow. I could use some review to avoid "surprises" in feature.

Comment: @xDaevax If you know any library that do such a thing, I would glad to hear about it.

Comment: @tower120 [Boost Multi-index Containers Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Quick review (in anticipation of more code).

The main issue I have with the code is that is not encapsulate in a class.

```
std::vector<Element> data;       // usual continious vector, no magic here
std::vector<int> key_indices;    // point to data[]. these values changes when erase/insert to data
std::vector<int> free_indices;
```

These are basically global variables and anybody can access an mutate them (not just maliciously but accidently). C++ has the ability to encapsulate all the parts of a class and protect it from accidental misuse by only allowing certain functions (methods) to access the raw underlying data.

```
class MultiIndexToElement
{
    private:
        std::vector<Element> data;         // usual continious vector, no magic here
        std::vector<int>     key_indices;  // point to data[]. these values changes when erase/insert to data
        std::vector<int>     free_indices;
    public:
        void emplace_back();
        Key get_key(std::vector<Element>::iterator iter);

        Value& operator[](Key key);            
        Value& operator[](int index);

        void erase(std::vector<Element>::iterator iter);

     private:
        template<class iter>
        void update_indices(iter from, iter to, int shift);
};
```

Now that we can see the interface clearly there are a couple of things you should watch for.

#### Const correctness.

A method that does not change the state of the object should be marked `const`. This tells the compiler that calling this method does not change the object.

```
      Key get_key(std::vector<Element>::iterator iter) const;
                                                  //   ^^^^^
```

This is important because objects get passed to functions by `const reference` a lot in C++ to avoid the cost of copying the object.

#### Element Access

Usually containers allow tow forms of element accesses. Mutating access and const accesses.

```
        Value&       operator[](int index);       // This allows mutating access.
        Value const& operator[](int index) const; // This allows const accesses.
```

#### Emplace Back.

Usually emplace back (a new form of push back). Creates the `Element` in place using one of `Elements` constructors. Your version only allows for Element to have zero parameter constructor.

It is usually written like this:

```
 template<Args... args>
 void emplace_back(Args&& args...) {
     data.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);     // pass arguments to constructor
     .... /* Other stuff you need */
 }
```

The `Args...` part is a new part of C++14 so you will need to tell your compiler to use the newer version of the standard (that's not a default yet). But usually this means adding `-std=c++14` to the command line.

#### Templatization

Your code does not allow for easy templatization. In fact you don't define `Value` in the code sample above. This is more easily solved using templates around a class.

```
template<typename Value>
class MultiIndexToElement
{
     /* STUFF */
};
```

Comment: The code in question is just condensed version of http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/044f33b3f219f3f9 (which is in the very bottom of the question). Could you show, instead, how to use boost::multi_index to achieve the same result?

Comment: emplace_back is different: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back